# tf variable not changing value when input parameters change

Tags: tensorflow

I was trying to assign a variable `y` in tensorflow which is to be dependent on `x`. But, even upon changing the value of `x`, `y` doesn't change.

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()
x=tf.Variable(4,name='x')

model = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess.run(model)
y=tf.Variable(2*x,name='y')

model = tf.global_variables_initializer()  
sess.run(model)

sess.run(x)  
sess.run(tf.assign(x,2))  
print(sess.run(y))
```

I am expecting an output `4`, but I'm getting `8`. Any help would be appreciated.

Gramercy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y=tf.Variable(2*x, name='y')` just means `y` will be **initialized** by `x*2`, change this line into `y = 2 * x` will do as you expected.

Comment: Cool! It worked :) But doesn't tf assign values to a variable when we run `sess.run`? I'm doing that in the last line when the value of `x` has been changed.

Comment: `y=tf.Variable(2*x, name='y')` the relationship between `y` and `x` is just `y` need initial value from `x`, but not related after value of `y` set. `y = 2*x` means that the value of `y` is dependent on `x`, it changes when `x` changes. If I made me clear, upvote and approve of this answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah sure!
Well, according to the docs, I see a `tf.Variable` is defined in a way that the first parameter provides the initial values. But I guess the fact that variables are allocated values when `sess.run` is called is a little misleading, isn't it? Moreover, the value of `x` has changed before `y` is alloted, so it's a little difficult for me to digest. :)

Comment: Variables are initialed and updated when `sess.run`. How the Variable is updated is define by the dependency chain of tensorflow graph. `y=tf.Variable(2*x,name='y')` will not add dependency chain but `y=2*x` will do. Once the dependency was created, when you getting value of `y` by calling `sess.run(y)`, it has to find all the values of which `y` is dependent on ,`x` in this case,  so it will compete the value of `y` by new value of `x`.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!